# Refresh Token in Interceptor before request is fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pulling my hair out on this one. I would like to refresh an access token if the user's access token is just about to expire.

`authService.isUserLoggedIn()` returns a promise and checks if the the user is logged in or not. If not the user's access token is being refreshed.

However the problem is that `authService.isUserLoggedIn()` is async call and before it returns the value, the interceptor will finish its job and the Authorization header will not be populated with the new token...

I was looking for a way to wait for the promise to resolve before the script continues. Unfortunately I'm not able to complete what is required.

Code:

```
.factory('SEHttpInterceptor', function($injector, ngWebApiSettings) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {

          // add Authorization header if available
          if (config.url.indexOf(ngWebApiSettings.apiServiceBaseUri) >-1){
            var authService = $injector.get('authService2');
              authService.isUserLoggedIn().then(function(response){
                var authData = $injector.get('$localStorage').getObject("authorizationData");
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
              });
          }   
          return config;
        }
      };
});
```

Comment: Have you tried returning the promise itself?

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! It worked, I am going to update the answer in a second!

Comment: You should consider this though: if you have multiple requests in the time it takes the token to refresh, you will be requesting to refresh the token several times, once for each pending request, and will be sending potentially different tokens. You will need to create a que of promises that are resolved when you refresh your token, and to make sure to request for the refresh only once,

Comment: Good comment. Storing a local variable in the authService should prevent other requests from generating refresh token?

Comment: Not exactly. One way to do this is this: Lets say you use a service to refresh your token. That service should hold an array of promises, where each promise represents a request to refresh the token. The service should be aware of the stack's state, and only request the new token once for the stack. Once the new token arrives, the service should resolve all of the requests with the new token and clear the stack. On the interceptor, you should return a promise that is resolved with the config object. The config promise should be resolved when the refresh token service resolves its promise.

Comment: @AvivShaked  thanks, did you have example of this behavior? update. i think , i found it https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Answer (score 2):

From AngularJS [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The interceptors leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this need for both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.
>
> `request`: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.

I'm assuming that you can simply:

```
'request': function(config) {

    if (config.url.indexOf(ngWebApiSettings.apiServiceBaseUri) === -1){
        return config;
    }

    var authService = $injector.get('authService2');
    return authService.isUserLoggedIn().then(function(response){
        var authData = $injector.get('$localStorage').getObject("authorizationData");
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        return config;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oleg's suggestion, I have managed to get this working. The answer was to return a promise, within which we return the `config` key.

```
.factory('SEHttpInterceptor', function($injector, ngWebApiSettings) {
     return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {

          // add Authorization header if available
          if (config.url.indexOf('/Token')== -1 && config.url.indexOf(ngWebApiSettings.apiServiceBaseUri) >-1){
            var authService = $injector.get('authService2');
              return authService.isUserLoggedIn().then(function(response){
                var authData = $injector.get('$localStorage').getObject("authorizationData");
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                return config;
              });
          }   
          return config;
        }
      };
    })
```